# SonataUser - Restricting selectable groups

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

It seems like a basic need but can't find any resource on the subject.

In the User Admin form, I need to filter the selectable groups depending on current user's roles.

Let's say we should only be able to select groups for which we are granted to all attached roles.

I think ACLs are not required here.

Could I use a voter ?
As it seems to me like a common need, could someone point me to any resource ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see the maddening rush to respond to my question, I'm going to give my humble contribution.

I have not been able to use ACL nor voters for that.

So I did a custom type extending `choice`

This type retrieves the groups from a service with `security.context` and `doctrine` injected.

This service have a function for gathering groups that have this little algorithm:

```php
public function allExistingGroups()
{
    $finalGroupsList = array();

    /* Get all existing groups */
    $groups = $this->doctrine->getRepository('SonataUserBundle:Group')
                             ->findAll();

    foreach ($groups as $group) {
        $isGranted = true;
        foreach ($group->getRoles() as $role) {
            if (!$this->securityContext->isGranted($role)) {
                $isGranted = false;
            }
        }
        /* User is granted, so he can see the group */
        if ($isGranted) {
            $finalGroupsList[$group->getId()] = $group->getName();
        }
    }

    return $finalGroupsList;
}
```

The user will now see only groups to which he is granted to all the roles.

For sure there should be a prettier solution, but this did the trick for me.